# Bad Request 400 when requesting Reddit OAuth2 token

Tags: rest, oauth, access-token, reddit, reddit-access-token

I am trying to use reddit api to send private message on behalf of the user. But I am not being able to complete the Oauth2 authorization to get an access token.

I am following the guide here: https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2

I have created a reddit developer app and I am following the code flow steps. After getting the `code` from the `authorization` endpoint, I make the following request to exchange the code for an access token.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token' \
--header 'User-Agent: *******' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic *******' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'code=*******' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:1410/'
```

But instead of the access token, I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "error": 400
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would guess that your Auth header is correct, otherwise you'd be seeing a 401 instead of a 400.  I would also guess that the redirect_uri is correct/acceptable because you passed the authorization step without error.  Some things I would try are: removing the User-Agent header and not urlencoding the parameters.  Really, those are just guesses.  I found nothing in that guide that indicates you are doing anything wrong and no documentation for what a 400 response means here other than the general understanding of that http status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a few months since the question was posted. I was finally able to solve it.

Here is what I was doing wrong.

After the user logs in and gives the app the necessary permission, you are redirected to a URL that contains the `code` parameter. I noticed that the codes have `#_` at the end. I just removed the trailing `#_` and made the same request in my original question and it worked.

Comment: This should have been mentioned in the official GitHub [documentation](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#retrieving-the-access-token), but unfortunately it's been archived since 2017.

Answer (score 0):

'I had the same issue. Turns out I selected application type as 'Script' in my app setting while I was following the Authorization steps for a different App Type(web)
Follow this one for Script:
https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example